# regular expression for xml format

Tags: java, regex

i'm trying to get **two** regular expressions for the next xml string:

```
<string name="mytag1">mycontent1</string>
<string name="mytag2">mycontent2</string>
<string name="mytag3">mycontent3</string>
```

My first need is to extract all **tags**, resulting:

```
mytag1
mytag2
mytag3
```

The second one is to extract all **contents**, resulting:

```
mycontent1
mycontent2
mycontent3
```

I've tried a lot of regex with no success, any ideas?  know that it is a bit tricky...  Thanks!!

Comment: `<string name="([^"]*)">([^<>]*)</string>` grab the string you want from index 1 and index 2.  Don't parse html files with regex.

Comment: thx for your answer but i've just tested on an online tester and it results blank...

Comment: If your requirement is extracting data from XML file then regex is a bad idea. Use a XML parser for the job.

Comment: That's because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Billyjoker really https://regex101.com/r/iF7dV0/4 ?

Comment: Ohh, it is ok, i will use a parser instead...thx

Comment: *`I've tried a lot of regex`* show us some of them!

Comment: Here's a tutorial to get you started with XML Parsing in Java:  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html  You should really always avoid regex for this type of stuff.  XML (and HTML) are not Regular Languages, therefore Regular Expressions aren't the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the `string` tags in your XML is really that flat and easy<sup>[1]</sup>, you may use regex:

```
<string name="(mytag\d+)">([^<]*)</string>
```

The parentheses catch

- `\1` the `name` attribute
- `\2` the content (provided that there is nothing nested in it)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Normally XML exceeds the power of regex. Regular expressions are good for fast lexicographic analysis, but hopelessly overburdened with recursive languages.